# ionic upload/login returning logging error while the email and password is correct

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm getting this error when I try to login or upload my app to Ionic View.

> Email: mehdinraza@gmail.com
>
> Password:
>
> Error logging in
>
> Email or Password incorrect. Please visit https://apps.ionic.io for
>   help. (CLI v1.7.12)
>
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 5.4.1 Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0 Gulp local:
>
> Ionic Version: 1.2.1
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
>
> Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
>
> Ios-deploy version: Not installed
>
> Ios-sim version: 5.0.4
>
> OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
>
> Node Version: v4.2.3
>
> Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/505)

Comment: I already tried this but still not working...